How does TFLite/LiteRT compute calibration values for quantization
I'm working on quantizing a TensorFlow Lite model using post-training quantization, and I'm trying to understand exactly how the min and max calibration parameters are computed.
From what I understand, the process involves:

Running inference on a calibration dataset
Collecting statistics on tensor values during these inference passes
Computing min and max values for quantization

However, I'm unclear on some specifics:

How exactly are the min and max values calculated across multiple calibration samples?
Are outliers handled in any special way, or is it a simple global min/max?
Are there any configurable parameters that affect how these min/max values are computed?

I've looked at the TensorFlow Lite documentation, but I couldn't find detailed information about this process. Any insights into the specific algorithm or code references would be greatly appreciated.
